# reinterpret_cast<volatile uint8_t*>(37)' is not a constant expression

Tags: c++, c++11, avr

`gcc` fails to compile the code below, while `clang` compiles ok. I have no control on the macro `PORTB`, as it is in a 3rd party library (`avr`).

Is it a `gcc` bug? How can I work around it in `gcc`? As a workaround is somehow possible to create a pre-processor macro which extracts the numerical value from PORTB?

Note this question is similar, but not identical to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54169791/reinterpret-cast-with-an-integer-literal-is-not-a-constexpr/54169953#54169953). 
It is also different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398102/constexpr-and-initialization-of-a-static-const-void-pointer-with-reinterpret-cas) question, where the developer has the flexibility to change the rhs of the assignment, thus avoiding the `reinterpret_cast`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

#define PORTB (*(volatile uint8_t *)((0x05) + 0x20))

struct PortB {
    static const uintptr_t port = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&PORTB);
};

int main() {
    std::cout << PortB::port << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [constexpr and initialization of a static const void pointer with reinterpret cast, which compiler is right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398102/constexpr-and-initialization-of-a-static-const-void-pointer-with-reinterpret-cas)

Comment: `g++ foo.cpp -std=c++11` works fine for me.

Comment: It used to work for me as well, but not anymore with latest `gcc` versions. I use `8.2.1`. See for instance: https://godbolt.org/z/TSOHN0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a constexpr pointer to a register on embedded system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67037386/how-to-create-a-constexpr-pointer-to-a-register-on-embedded-system)

Comment: @user3840170: The answer seems to be that it is impossible as you see in the linked question. It feels like a real language bug! It makes it impossible to use vendor provided register definitions anymore in constant expressions anymore. This breaks tons of my code... Now a have to write my own code parser to create linker scripts. Bad change to the language!

Answer (score 1):

It seems [`reinterpret_cast` is not allowed during compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59913380/5534993). Thus the newer version of the compiler simply is [more conforming to the language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54061762/5534993). `reinterpret_cast` will not be allowed where a `constexpr` is required.

But maybe these workaround may help ([compiles with g++ 9.2](https://godbolt.org/z/yTfRYj)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

#define PORTB (*(volatile uint8_t *)((0x05) + 0x20))

struct PortB {
    static uintptr_t port; 
};

uintptr_t PortB::port = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&PORTB);
const uintptr_t freePort = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&PORTB);
#define macroPort reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&PORTB)

int main() {
    std::cout << PortB::port << "\n";
    std::cout << freePort << "\n";
    std::cout << macroPort << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will not work as einterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&PORTB) is not a constant expression anymore. Youcan't use the expression nor the macro inside any constexpr expression like as NTTP or others. For me a real language bug!