# Why can't reinterpret_cast be used in a constant expression?

Tags: c++, constexpr

I've run into the following error:

```
class NormalClass
{
public:
    constexpr NormalClass() : arr{}, debug_ptr((int*)arr)
    {
//'reinterpret_cast' is not a constant expression
//cast that performs the conversions of a reinterpret_cast is not allowed in a constant expression
    }

public:

    char arr[5];
    int* debug_ptr;


};

constinit NormalClass normal;

int main()
{

}
```

Originally this was in a template, with (T*) cast. Why is it that a cast like this isn't allowed in a constexpr?

Comment: Whether the compiler would use `reinterpret_cast` for `(T*)` or not depends on the type that is cast, and the type it is cast to. If it works with `(T*)` then the compiler didn't choose `reinterpret_cast`

Comment: With the title, the question might be a duplicate to [Why is reinterpret_cast not constexpr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59913275/why-is-reinterpret-cast-not-constexpr) You might want to show the code with a [mcve] that utilizes the template and `(T*)` including the types involved with the cast and the same for your current example, and then it would be possible to tell why the one works and the other not

Comment: Not an answer; but if you replace both occurrences of `int*` with `unsigned int` (or `unsigned long` in a 64-bit environment), it compiles without warnings.

Comment: This is probably for the best as don't think that's a valid cast. How would you ever get to the last element of the `char` array?

Comment: Oh it came up when I had my own array container that had a char buffer, and I couldn't see anything in it in the debugger through the char pointer, so I wanted to create a debug pointer cast to T.

Comment: If your compiler has good enough C++20 coverage, you could try using [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) to do the cast.  It's `constexpr`.  _"couldn't see anything in it in the debugger through the char pointer"_ might be best to study your debugger docs - there's usually an easy way to tell it to display memory content as if it contained some arbitrary type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why can't reinterpret_cast be used in a constant expression?

Because the C++ language spec says so. See [[expr.const]/5.15](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#5.15):

> An expression `E` is a *core constant expression* unless the evaluation of `E`, ... would evaluate one of the following:
>
> 5.15   a `reinterpret_­cast` ([[expr.reinterpret.cast]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.reinterpret.cast));

---

Also note that reinterpreting `char[]` as `int` and then accessing it is undefined behavior - a [strict aliasing violation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7005988/485343). As soon as the pointer `debug_ptr` is dereferenced in the actual program, there will be UB.

Comment: That's really the one I was looking for ;) Couldn't find the reference quickly enough. Thanks

Comment: To avoid strict aliasing what can you do if you want an int pointer pointing to the char buffer? And don't say create an int array instead.

Answer (score 3):

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression

**Core constant expressions**

A core constant expression is any expression whose evaluation would not evaluate any one of the following:

- 17. reinterpret_cast