# Casting a constexpr value to a pointer via reinterpret cast

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, constexpr

Coming from C and embedded background, register addresses are often used and cast to pointers:

```
#define REG_A_ADDR       0x80000000

uint32_t ptr_reg_a = (uint32_t*) REG_A_ADDR;
```

However, C++ emphasizes usage of `constexpr` for compile time constants and that is more typesafe.

The following is the equivalent version I came up with but it doesn't compile, since `reinterpret_cast` can't be used with `constexpr`, seemingly:

```
constexpr uint32_t reg_a_addr = 0x80000000;

constexpr uint32_t *ptr_reg_a = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(reg_a_addr); // constexpr variable 'reg_a_addr' must be initialized by a constant expression
```

So, since the above snippet errors out, what's the practical approach around it? Using `const` compiles fine but is it practical?

Comment: The key word in your narrative "is more typesafe". Does this whole thing look typesafe to you?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369606/constexpr-pointer-value

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't see anything wrong with the types being used here.

Comment: Ignoring the issue of `constexpr` for a moment: without a cast of, some kind, this code will not compile. As such, a cast, here, defeats C++'s type-safety, by definition.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you asking me to write a code with main() and that actually runs in a compiler? Why do you think the cast here defeats type safety?

Comment: why can't `reinterpret_cast<uint32_t* {aka unsigned int*}>(2147483648)' ` be a constant expression? or rather a compile time? my actual question though is about an alternative code

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59913380/4123703) might answer your question. I presume that standard doesn't want to allow a source of UB (`reinterpret_cast`) to be handled in compile time. In another way, it might be UB in runtime, so how to implement it in compile time which doesn't allow UB in all the cases?

Comment: @LouisGo That exactly answers OP question. Cheers!

Comment: *"using `const` compiles fine but is it practical?"* -- You might have to define what you mean by "practical". I'd be inclined to say that using `const` is practical *because* it compiles fine, combined with it being not excessively long. Apparently you have a different definition of "practical" than me, so it would help if you included your definition in the question.

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen I disagree. The link provided by Louis Go answers *why* this situation exists, but the question is *how* to work around this situation. It's a useful link, but it does not exactly answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

Although I'm not *entirely* sure what you mean by "type safe"<sup>1,2</sup> in this context, you can use `const` with the appropriate `...ptr_t` type to ensure that the (constant) value you provide is valid for the pointer.

Take the following code, for example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

// I added an extra zero to your constant - now it's too big for a 32-bit pointer
constexpr uintptr_t reg_a_addr = 0x800000000; // uintptr_t is platform-specific
uint32_t* const ptr_reg_a = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t* const>(reg_a_addr);
// ^ Note that "const unit32_t* ptr_reg_a ..." declares a pointer to a constant;
// the version I have given defines a constant pointer to (potentially) writable memory.

int main()
{
    std::cout << ptr_reg_a << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

When targeting the x64 platform with MSVC, this compiles without warning and produces the expected output:

```
0000000800000000
```

However, when targeting the x86 (32 bit) platform, the compiler will issue warnings that the value is too big:

> warning C4305: 'initializing': truncation from '__int64' to 'const
> uintptr_t'
>  warning C4309: 'initializing': truncation of constant
> value

And, indeed, the output will be the truncated value:

```
00000000
```

As to whether or not it is *practical* – well, it compiles but trying to use a `constexpr` with `reinterpret_cast` doesn't, so I guess it is!

---

Note that the clang-cl compiler in Visual Studio 2022 (when targeting 32 bits) gives an 'equivalent' warning for the constant being too big:

> warning : implicit conversion from 'long long' to 'const uintptr_t'
> (aka 'const unsigned int') changes value from 34359738368 to 0
> [-Wconstant-conversion]

---

<sup>1</sup> Maybe, by "type safe," you mean that reassigning a new value to that pointer will be prevented at compile time … in which case: Yes, it is type safe, as code like the following will not compile:

```cpp
    uint32_t q = 42;
    ptr_reg_a = &q;
```

> error : cannot assign to variable 'ptr_reg_a' with const-qualified
> type 'uint32_t *const' (aka 'unsigned int *const')

<sup>2</sup> If you are asking whether or not using `const` rather than `constexpr` will make such a pointer any less strictly typed, then: No, it won't. However, (IIRC) the C++ Standard does impose stricter requirements for diagnostics on potential misuse of `constexpr` values … but many (if not most) mainstream compilers will, if warnings are fully enabled, provide suitable diagnostics for cases of (say) violation of strict aliasing rules, or other usage of such a pointer that exhibits undefined behaviour.